# Is t possible to use get_fieldname_display() as annotate value?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Is it possible to use get_fieldname_display() as annotate value?

```
queryset.filter(is_draft=True).annotate(status=get_status_display() )
```

If yes, how do I do this and is there a pythonic or better way to do this?

Comment: No, but why would you want to? The queryset is a list of instances, each of which has a `get_status_display()` method already, so you can just call it.

Comment: I need to format my data in order to use it in charts. Basically, I need to group the result by dates and categories then sum up the values.

Comment: Fine. What's stopping you doing that?

Comment: getting the choice label of the value  :( .please take note that the value is dynamic as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotation, but it would be a little more complex. First, you would have to have the choices in a separate variable, used in model and a query:

```
statuses = [
    ('status1', 'status display number 1'),
    ('status2', 'status display number 2'),
     # ...
]
class YourModel(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=statuses)
    # rest of your model
```

Then a queryset would look like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When

YourModel.objects.filter(
    is_draft=True
).annotate(
    status_display=zone_order=Case(
        *[When(status=s[0], then=Value(s[1])) for s in statuses],
        output_field=CharField()
    )
)
```

You can use this annotation trick in managers too, to override get_queryset. I do not know the implications to lazy translation of such an approach, however. Disclaimer: I did not test it on a live interpreter, so bugs possible.